# In Xcode, why do some packages have different icons and can't run tests?

Tags: xcode, xcode13

In Xcode, if I look in the scheme menu for my app project, I see some of the Swift packages on which I have declared dependencies.

Some of them have gear icons, and some of them have building icons. The ones with the gear icons do not allow me to run unit tests. In one such package, I want to run unit tests, so I'd like to know how to get from one state to the other.

I observe three different states for different packages:

1. In the menu with gear.
2. In the menu with building icon. (Can run tests)
3. Not in the menu at all.

What does the gear mean, as opposed to the building icon? Why are the different packages in the 3 different states. How do I get to #2, so I can run unit tests for the package?

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have the same thing :(